# Memory leak issues with setTimeout in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have  a javascript code to control the animation a moving div.In this I used setTimeout to make the div move. you can click on the following link to play the animation.

```
     `http://jsfiddle.net/dudling007/PfPzj/3/`
```

The problem is that after playing the animation, whenever I clicked a couple of time on pause and resume buttons , it takes a lot of memory and the clicking of the pause buttons also become so slow. I saw the %CPU and real memory consumption from the activity monitor of the MAC OSX.Can someone please help me what is the problem in the code that is consuming some much memory after clicking the pause button 10 -14 times.

Comment: When a notice says accompany your jsFiddle link with code, it's for a reason.

Comment: You might want to use jQuery().animate().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory leak happens because `$('#pause_button').click` event is set every time `moveCard` method is called. Button bindings should be moved out of the 
"object" cycle.

You can use tool link [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) for [firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) to check console log of javascript.
Here is your example with log on pause button. This should be happen only once. http://jsfiddle.net/Th6ha/1/

```
$('#pause_button').click(function() { 
console.log('pause pressed');
                      arrayObject.pause(wStart,lStart,wEnd,lEnd);
                      $('#resume_button').css('display','inline-block');
                      $('#pause_button').css('display','none');

                      });
```

You can consider using  method [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#example-0) of jquery